# update con dos tablas

Tags: sql-server

Quiero realizar un update a la tabla referencia el campo que quiero actualizar es el tipo_activo y solo esta en la tabla (activo), lo que une a activo y a referencia es el campo (referencia).

La tabla activo tiene varias secuencias ejemplo (223,225,2654,455,530) y esas secuencias tiene un tipo de activo que es el (3) yo quiero cambiar solo  2 secuencias de activo que son las (455 y 530) pero cuando corro el update me actualiza todo lo que tengo esa referencia, solicito ayuda para poder realizar mi update bien.

> tabla REFERENCIA : campos referencia
>   tabla ACTIVO : campos referencia, tipo_activo, secuencia_activo

```
update REFERENCIA
set REFERENCIA.TIPO_ACTIVO = 4
WHERE
REFERENCIA.TIPO_ACTIVO = '3'
AND REFERENCIA IN
  (SELECT REFERENCIA
  FROM ACTIVO
  WHERE secuencia_activo in (455, 530) AND  REFERENCIA  = 2110260024  ) ;
```

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara. Te sugiero que [modifques tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/29612/edit) y que por lo menos agregues lo siguiente: 1) Una muestra de los datos actuales de ambas tablas 2) Los datos tal como los quieres después de un `update` que funcione bien.

Comment: los campos de la tabla REFERENCIA SON (referencia)
los campos de la tabla ACTIVO SON: (referencia, tipo_activo, secuencia_activo)

y los datos que quiero cambiar es el tipo_activo con numero de secuencia 455 y 530, el tipo de activo actualmente esta en 3 quiero ponerlo en 4.

Comment: Una de las cosas que no entiendo es que dices que tu `update` no hace lo que quieres, pero por lo menos corre, ¿sí? Pero tu `update` hace referencia a `REFERENCIA.TIPO_ACTIVO`, dando a entener que el campo `TIPO_ACTIVO` pertenece a la tabla `REFERENCIA`. Pero según tu explicación, el campo `TIPO_ACTIVO` no pertenece a la tabla `REFERENCIA`. ¿Notas la contradicción?

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez lo que necesitas es hacer un [inner join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) a las dos tablas, para quitar la sub-sentencia. Pero la explicación de la estructura de tus tablas no es muy clara.

Dejo un ejemplo de como se haría con el update, tal vez no es exacto a lo que necesitas, necesitarías explicar mejor la estructura de los campos de tus tablas.

```
UPDATE  A
SET A.TIPO_ACTIVO = 4
FROM REFERENCIA A
INNER JOIN ACTIVO B ON A.REFERENCIA = B.REFERENCIA
WHERE B.SECUENCIA_ACTIVO IN (455,530) AND A.TIPO_ACTIVO = 3 AND B.REFERENCIA = 2110260024
```

Comment: si me funciono, gracias

Comment: @Angel: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)